# error in recoding

Tags: r

Trying to recode my missing values to `NA` in `R` with the `epicalc` package, I get the following error:

```
 recode(trstlglR, 99 , NA, dataFrame=ESSround5)
 Error in search()[[pos]] : attempt to select more than one element
```

Although the command seems to do what I want, I am afraid I am missing something. The dataframe is too large to check every value. Anyone have any experience with this?

Replicable example:

```
structure(list(trstlglR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 
0L), trstplcR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), plcarcrR = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("trstlglR", 
"trstplcR", "plcarcrR"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5714L, 2450L, 
2980L, 3837L, 6136L, 2197L, 2198L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: seems like you have to first do `use(ESSround5)` before doing `recode`.

Comment: @Arun Indeed the error is gone.

Comment: @GaryWeissman, you don't need `apply`. you can just do: `df$x[df$x == 99] <- NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `?recode`, the examples first do:

```
use(.data)
```

before running `recode`. Now, if you read what is `?use`, then you'll find this:

> 'use' reads in datasets from Dbase (.dbf), Stata (.dta), SPSS(.sav), EpiInfo(.rec) and Comma separated value (.csv) formats as well as R data frames. The destination data frame is saved in memory, by default as '.data', and automatically attached to the search path. **This setting is the basis for other commands of 'epicalc' including 'des', 'summ', 'recode', 'label.var' etc.**

So what you'll have to do is:

```
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:3, 20, replace=T), y=sample(20))

use(df) # first to copy this to .data and attach.
recode(x, 2, NA, df) # not it should work without errors

#     x  y
# 1  NA 15
# 2  NA  6
# 3  NA  3
# 4   3  8
# 5  NA  1
# 6  NA 16
# 7   3  5
# 8   3  9
# 9   1 10
# 10  3 20
# 11 NA 11
# 12  1  4
# 13 NA  2
# 14 NA 12
# 15  1 13
# 16  3 17
# 17 NA 18
# 18  3 19
# 19  1  7
# 20  1 14
```

Comment: Although the error is gone, my max value now stays 99?
`> use(ESSround5)
> recode(trstlglR, 99 , NA, ESSround5)
> summary(trstlglR)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1798  0.0000 99.0000`

Comment: Are you sure there are values > 99? I'ved edited the post to show the output for my example. And it seems to do it right..

Comment: Not larger than 99, only exactly 99. This is sure since max = 99 in the summary. Should they be larger than?

Comment: Please post your data by editing your post if you want me to debug what's going on with your data. I don't have access to it and all I can do is say that it works in the test example I've posted.

Comment: You can look at my post to get an idea of how I (or SO community) expects the data to have a reproducible example.

Comment: I added an example. However, I solved the issue. The `use` function did not attach the dataset as I thought. So I was getting the summary of a non-recoded version. Thanks